# controller for knockout.js custom element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Sometimes a component/custom element has some UI logic which requires some UI code, it's something which can't be done by binding to the component's view-model.

For example, let's say the component needs to change the way it looks based on available space, and this requires manipulating elements by JavaScript code.

What I need is a controller for the UI.

For example, imagine we have a component called myGadget for which I have myGadget.html, myGadgetViewModel.js and I also want to have myGadgetView.js

Within the myGadgetView.js I want to have something like this:

```
function myGadgetView(element)
{
      // element is the custom element's node
}
```

What is the best way to do this in Knockout?

Should I combine component with custom binding?

With a custom binding I could get access to the element, so the HTML of the component would look like this:

```
<script id="myBar-template">
  <div data-bind="myGadget : ...">
  </div>
</script>
```

and I need to put somewhere this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myGadget = { 
   init: function (element, valueAccessor) 
   { 
      // I have access to element node
      var myGadgetView = new myGadgetView(element);
   },
   update: function (element, valueAccessor) 
   { 
      // I have access to element node
   }
}
```

I'm not sure about using custom binding for this, I wonder if there's a better approach.

For example, I'm looking to the custom component loading, but I don't have a clear idea yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining a component, you can specify a `createViewModel` function. This function will be passed the element the component will be bound to. According the [Knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html#a-createviewmodel-factory-function), it's still preferable to use custom bindings to manipulate the view.

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot about componentInfo.element in createViewModel. I still think I need a controller object because unless I'm mistaken, the binding handler is state-less, it only has static callbacks

Answer (score 0):

Any manipulation of the view should be done in binding handlers, but that doesn't mean you can't make something like a jQuery plug-in, which your `myGadgetView.js` would be, and use that in the binding handler. You just wouldn't want your plug-in to be aware of your viewmodel, nor your viewmodel to be aware of the plug-in. The binding handler would mediate, mapping viewmodel elements to plug-in parameters.

Comment: thanks. I definitely do not want to have the controller aware of the view-model, nor vice-versa. so you're saying custom binding handler is the way to go, in the way I described? With a custom binding handler I have a feeling of over-engineering..

Comment: Binding handlers exist to ensure that the view reflects the viewmodel and vice-versa, so there is no view-handling code in your viewmodel. It is not unusual to need to write one. This is exactly what it's for.